# How to properly handle a deserialize JSON object

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net, json-deserialization

This is the first time I have deserialized a complex JSON string. This is my model:

```
public class Child
    {
        public List<object> children { get; set; }
        public bool var { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool leaf { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Datum
    {
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
        public bool var { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool leaf { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I deserialized the string using:

`RootObject rootobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Body);`

Here is my result:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jiMA.png

How can i handle this result properly? I am using ASP.NET and how can I get the children data inside the parent data and how can I use them all? I searched the  internet for days but all of the help get me to deserialize the JSON response and not on how to use them. Thank you for your answers.

And here is my Json data

https://anotepad.com/notes/h96yqk

Comment: How did you get to that JSON structure in your classes? It doesn't represent your JSON data at all

Comment: Hi Camilo i used Json2Csharp

Comment: From quickly looking at the classes you defined the class `Child` should not exist and the class `Datum` should have a list of type `List<Datum>`

Comment: what exactly do you think is the issue with your result? What do you mean by "properly"? The result looks like pretty much what you'd expect if you deserialise to that structure (which btw, contrary to the comments above, I don't think is especially problematic on the face of it). `data` is an array, so `List<Datum>` looks correct, then you've got `children` inside that as another array. So if you want to get the children, you have to iterate or search through those lists, just like any other C# list. So are you really asking how to use a list in C#?

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop why would the `Child` class not exist? It's clearly there to represent an instance of an item in the (outer) `children` array in the JSON

Comment: P.S. The only worry I have about this deserialisation is whether you are able to be certain that the structure of the JSON will be the same every time you download it? To me it looks like it's describing some sort of tree structure. Is there a limit to the depth of the tree and the number of layers of children there will be? If that's not predictable, then deserialising to a fixed class structure may not be practical. You might have to use `dynamic` or `JArray` and `JObject` instead to give you flexibility.

Comment: @ADyson the whole thing looks to be an array of a single class. Whether you call it `Child` or `Datum` does not matter, although I wouldn't create 2 classes that hold exactly the same properties (with the assumption that `Child` wrongly has a `List<object>` and should be `List<Child>` or `List<Datum>`). It would also easier and more generic to make a flat structure from it.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop that's true, I admit I hadn't noticed that both class definitions were identical. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your model should look like:

```
public class Datum
{
    public List<Datum> children { get; set; }
    public bool var { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool leaf { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a flat structure of the json result. This allows you to iterate through all the objects as if it were a single array (which I assumed you wanted to do with the data).

```
var flat = root.data.SelectMany(x => x.SelectChilds(y => y.children));
```

Extension method to help create the flat structure:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive method to return a flat structure of child elements
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="func">Function to get child elements</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectChilds<T>(this T source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> func)
    {
        yield return source;
        foreach (T element in func(source) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())
        {
            var subs = element.SelectChilds(func);
            foreach (T sub in subs)
            {
                yield return sub;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill try it now thank you